# python34 ImportError: No module named 'rpm'

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, rpm

Решил попробовать написать небольшой скрипт для поиска новой версии *rpm*-пакета.

Вот такой код:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4

import os
import sys
import rpm

def readRpmHeader(ts, filename):
    """ read an rpm header. """
    fd = os.open(filename, os.O_RDONLY)
    h = None
    try:
        h = ts.hdrFromFdno(fd)
    except rpm.error as e:
        if str(e) == "error reading package header":
            sys.stderr.write(str(e))
        h = None
    finally:
        os.close(fd)
    return h


def main(argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        sys.stderr.write("Usage: %s PACKAGE_NAME...\n" % (argv[0],))
        return 1

    ts = rpm.TransactionSet()
    ts.setVSFlags(rpm._RPMVSF_NOSIGNATURES | rpm._RPMVSF_NODIGESTS)
    fresh_rpms = {}
    for f in argv[1:]:
        if not os.path.exist(f):
            sys.stderr.write("Error: file %r was not found!" % f)
            return 1
    h = readRpmHeader(ts, f)
    name = h[rpm.RPMTAG_NAME]
    if (name not in fresh_rpms
            or rpm.versionCompare(h, fresh_rpms[name]['header']) > 0):
        fresh_rpms[name] = {'header': h, 'filename': f}
    for n, v in fresh_rpms.iteritems():
        print (v['filename'])

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Выдает ошибку

> ImportError: No module named 'rpm'

Менял версии *python* на 2.7 и на 3.3 - не помогло...

Запустил `ipython` и проделал все операции вручную, все работает, `import rpm` не ругался и дал выполнить команды.

Вот что есть:

```
rpm -qa | grep rpm
rpm-build-4.11.1-25.el7.x86_64
python-deltarpm-3.6-3.el7.x86_64
atrpms-repo-7-7.el7.x86_64
redhat-rpm-config-9.1.0-68.el7.centos.noarch
rpm-python-4.11.1-25.el7.x86_64
rpm-4.11.1-25.el7.x86_64
rpm-sign-4.11.1-25.el7.x86_64
perl-srpm-macros-1-8.el7.noarch
rpm-libs-4.11.1-25.el7.x86_64
deltarpm-3.6-3.el7.x86_64
rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64
rpm-build-libs-4.11.1-25.el7.x86_64
```

Как можно решить проблему? или в чем, кроме прокладки между монитором и стулом, проблема?

А вот `rpm -ql rpm-python` показывает. что есть такой модуль.

```
# rpm -ql rpm-python
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/__init__.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/__init__.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/_rpmbmodule.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/_rpmmodule.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/_rpmsmodule.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/transaction.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/transaction.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/transaction.pyo
```

Проверял в папках `/usr/lib64/python3/site-packages/` и `/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/` - в обоих нет такого.

но запустив внутри интерпретатора `python3.4`

```
help('modules')
# получаю в ответ что rpm есть
```

Затем перегрузил машину и получаю ошибку при запуске скрипта

```
# запуск скрипта с папкой с rpm  пакетами
./rpm.py /home/firefedot/pts/files/

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rpm.py", line 46, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "./rpm.py", line 27, in main
    ts = rpm.TransactionSet()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TransactionSet'
```

типа нет атрибату, но стоит запустить тот же скрипт или любой *IDE* (у меня *NetBeans*) в котором есть `import rpm`  - получаю:

```
File "/home/firefedot/NetBeansProjects/hello/src/hello.py", line 5, in     <module>
    import rpm
ImportError: No module named 'rpm'
```

Если запустить с дебагером системы

```
gdb ./rpm.py /home/firefedot/pts/files/

"/home/firefedot/pts/./rpm.py": not in executable format: Формат файла не распознан
"/home/firefedot/pts/files/389-ds-base-devel-1.3.3.1-15.el7_1.x86_64.rpm" is not a core dump: Формат файла не распознан
```

То он ругается на первый же файл, хотя в коде указано смотреть со второго

```
for f in argv[1:]:
        if not os.path.exist(f):
            sys.stderr.write("Error: file %r was not found!" % f)
            return 1
```

но и rpm  не применяет.

А если запустить `ipython` и в нем запустить *pdb*  -выдает вот что:

```
In [1]: import pdb

In [2]: pdb.run('rpm.py /home/firefedot/pts/files')
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) c
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-47133b27bb55> in <module>()
----> 1 pdb.run('rpm.py /home/firefedot/pts/files')

/usr/lib64/python2.7/pdb.pyc in run(statement, globals, locals)
   1236 
   1237 def run(statement, globals=None, locals=None):
-> 1238     Pdb().run(statement, globals, locals)
   1239 
   1240 def runeval(expression, globals=None, locals=None):

/usr/lib64/python2.7/bdb.pyc in run(self, cmd, globals, locals)
    398             cmd = cmd+'\n'
    399         try:
--> 400             exec cmd in globals, locals
    401         except BdbQuit:
    402             pass

<string> in <module>()

NameError: name 'rpm' is not defined
```

не определена/но, говорит, *rpm*.

У меня система *CentOS7x64*,  пробовал то же самое на *Ubuntu 15.04* - тот же результат...

Что может быть, как ему показать, чтобы он все увидел?

Comment: к слову: `ipython` и `python` — это «две большие разницы».

Comment: Так то в курсе... проверил везде.. но проще от этого не становиться)

Comment: переименовать файл не пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал, результат тот же

Comment: кстати, попробовал запустить ваш скрипт на паре машин — ошибка синтаксиса в строке `except ...`.

Comment: а если заменить except rpm.error as e: на except rpm.error, e: ?    А на import  rpm  не ругается?

Comment: нет, import-ом все машины довольны. проверил ещё на паре машин: не нравится rpm.TransactionSet — нету, мол, такого метода. чтоб вы особо не переживали — все протестированные машины — без всяких centos-ов вообще и без rpm в частности. но «питоновский» модуль для работы с rpm — имеется.

Comment: тогда более чем странно... хотя и в инете нашел примеры, что с этого начитается  все... что за .. ерунда то... ну и переживать/не переживать .. а как жить дальше то?)))

Comment: Может это bug?  и мне повезло его поймать илиможет  в августочком релизе всех версий это заменили? не могу найти правда этого ни где...

Comment: Вот тут . аж несколько примеров с rpm.TransactionSet() http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/14291/rpm.TransactionSet Или может все таки что-то отключили в обновлении ?

Comment: так я разве против? кстати, вспомнил, где под рукой centos есть. запустил. но там python2.4 и «invalid syntax» в букве `s` в слове `as` в строке `except rpm.error as e:`.

Comment: на 2 питоне надо except rpm.error, e: (as  заменить на запятую)... но более того .. сейчас зашел в 3 питон и ввел  import rpm   затем dir(rpm)  и был удивлен, всего 13 модулей(методов), сделав тоже самое во 2 версии, получил просто  огромное количество методов. в числе которых, была transaction...  а поставив на свою голову тестовую 3,5 питона, там вообще нет возможности  импорта rpm  и теперь ни одна версия 3 питона  не импортирует rpm... либо полностью убрали, либо как то хитро запрятали...

Comment: *as заменить на запятую* — теперь «invalid syntax» в букве `y` в слове `finally` в 17-й строке. это не «на 2 питоне» а на *python2.4.3*.

Comment: но что еще странней. так это то что на второй машине с ubuntu  спустя полчаса так же dir(rpm) выдал 13. а не очень много моделей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решил проблему на Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 24 2015, 00:41:19)

На удивление, пришлось немного повозиться... 
вот итоговый код, в котором убран except и весь блок try
закоментировал строки для наглядности. (затем все вернулобратно и код заработал почти полностью, но проблему выявил, а то что код корявый - это уже решаемо)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os
import sys
import rpm

def readRpmHeader(ts, filename):
    print("fnc-readRpmHeader")
    """ read an rpm header. """
    fd = os.open(filename, os.O_RDONLY)
    h = None
    try:
    h = ts.hdrFromFdno(fd)
    except rpm.error, e:
        if str(e) == "error reading package header":
            sys.stderr.write(str(e))
        h = None
    finally:
        os.close(fd)
    return h


def main(argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        sys.stderr.write("Usage: %s PACKAGE_NAME...\n" % (argv[0],))
        return 1

    ts = rpm.TransactionSet()
    ts.setVSFlags(rpm._RPMVSF_NOSIGNATURES | rpm._RPMVSF_NODIGESTS)
    fresh_rpms = {}
    for f in argv[1:]:
        if not os.path.exists(f):
            sys.stderr.write("Error: file %r was not found!" % f)
            return 1
    h = readRpmHeader(ts, f)
    name = h[rpm.RPMTAG_NAME]
    if (name not in fresh_rpms
            or rpm.versionCompare(h, fresh_rpms[name]['header']) > 0):
    fresh_rpms[name] = {'header': h, 'filename': f}
    for n, v in fresh_rpms.iteritems():
        print (v['filename'])

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Самое не понятное. это то что этот код с небольшими правками в отключении тегов и except заверля на python2.7,  который есть из коробки на CentOS7. А как только добавил на ту машину питон3, сразу перестал работать ... не понятно в чем именно проблема и конфликт. И интересно, что код сработал один раз на ubuntu 15.04, как писал в комментарии выше, после чего перестал видеть методы rpm.

Итогом скажу.. что на сырой машине с версией 2,7 код работает как надо.
Делаю вывод, может и ошибочный, но в 3 версии либо отказываются от rpm/yum  и подобного, либо упрятали в какой-нибудь другой модуль.

Спасибо за оказание помощи. думаю можно как то закрыть эту ветку.
еще раз спасибо.